# Why can I not get my variables to populate properly from my JSON file into their individual categories

Tags: python, json, tkinter

So I'm trying to create a relatively simple python program that the main purpose is to have a library of parts used on a job, and it would allow me to upload an excel or manually select what parts were used on that job and then it would create a master PDF of all of the data sheets. I have the PDF portion completely figured out, but am having some difficulty dealing with Tkinter and the GUI and JSON file for saving between uses. I have buttons that allow the user to add a part, providing the part name, pathfile for the PDF and what the brand is (to separate out the parts list), and it will properly save to the JSON file, but when I try and have it repopulate the checkboxes within the GUI it doesn't work. So currently I have been trying to figure out why even if the JSON file is edit, and the program is rerun, the parts aren't being pushed to the GUI. I've messed up some of my functionality trying to figure this out but here is the section of my code I've been working with.

```
checkboxes_frame = None  # Declare checkboxes_frame as a global variable
canvas = None
parts = {}
checkboxes_frames = {}
checkboxes = {}  # Define the checkboxes dictionary

def update_checkboxes(notebook, parts):
    global checkboxes_frames, checkboxes

    for brand, brand_parts in parts.items():
        # Check if the brand already has a tab
        brand_tab = None
        for tab in notebook.tabs():
            if notebook.tab(tab, option="text") == brand:
                brand_tab = tab
                break

        if brand_tab is None:
            # Create a new tab for the brand if it doesn't exist
            brand_tab = ttk.Frame(notebook)
            notebook.add(brand_tab, text=brand)
            checkboxes_frames[brand_tab] = ttk.Frame(brand_tab)
            checkboxes[brand] = []

        checkboxes_frame = checkboxes_frames[brand_tab]

        for part, var in brand_parts.items():
            if part not in checkboxes[brand]:
                checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(checkboxes_frame, text=part, variable=var)
                checkbox.pack(pady=5)
                checkboxes[brand].append(part)

    # Update the scroll region whenever the checkboxes frame changes size
    def update_scroll_region(event):
        canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

    checkboxes_frame.bind('<Configure>', update_scroll_region)

    # Create a window inside the canvas and place the checkboxes frame
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=checkboxes_frame, anchor="nw")
def create_main_window():
    global checkboxes_frame, canvas
    global menu_bar
    menu_bar = tk.Menu(window)
    window.config(menu=menu_bar)

    settings_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=False)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=settings_menu)

    settings_menu.add_command(label="Open Settings", command=open_settings)

    # Create a notebook with tabs
    notebook = ttk.Notebook(window)
    notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")  # Set columnspan to 5

    load_settings()


    global parts
    # Dictionary to store the parts checkboxes for each brand

    load_parts()
    brands = list(parts.keys())

    def create_default_brands():
        # Brands
        brands = ['ABB', 'Alps', 'Other']

    if not brands:
        create_default_brands()

    for brand in brands:
        # Create a frame for each tab
        tab = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        notebook.add(tab, text=brand)

        # Create a scrollable frame
        scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(tab)
        scrollable_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        # Create a canvas
        canvas = tk.Canvas(scrollable_frame)
        canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Add a scroll bar
        scroll_bar = ttk.Scrollbar(scrollable_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
        scroll_bar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        # Configure the canvas and scroll bar
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)
        canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e, c=canvas: c.configure(scrollregion=c.bbox("all")))

        # Create a frame inside the canvas to hold the checkboxes
        global checkboxes_frame
        checkboxes_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

        # Add additional parts for ABB TESTING FUNCTION ########################################
        if brand == "ABB":
            additional_parts = ["FA-TH", "CBX-8R8-H", "FLX-4R4-H", "FLX-8R8-H"]
            for part in additional_parts:
                var = tk.IntVar()
                checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(checkboxes_frame, text=part, variable=var)
                checkbox.pack(pady=5)
                parts[brand][part] = var

    update_checkboxes(notebook, parts)
create_main_window()
```

Here is an example of the JSON file I'm using:

```
{
"ABB": {
    "FA-TH": 0,
    "CBX-8R8-H": 0,
    "FLX-4R4-H": 0,
    "FLX-8R8-H": 0
},
"Alps": {
    "Part 1": 0,
    "Part 2": 0,
},
"Other": {
    "Part 1": 0,
    "Part 2": 0,
}
```

}

For reference here is the rest of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog, messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import os
import json
import shutil
import pandas as pd

settings = {}
parts = {}

def save_settings():
    parts_data = {brand: {part: var.get() for part, var in tab_parts.items()} for brand, tab_parts in parts.items()}

    # Save the parts to JSON file
    with open('parts.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(parts_data, file)


def load_settings():
    try:
        with open('settings.json', 'r') as file:
            settings.update(json.load(file))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        settings.update({
            'master_folder_path': '',
            'template_folder_path': '',
        })


def save_parts():
    parts_data = {}
    for brand in parts:
        if isinstance(parts[brand], str):
            parts_data[brand] = parts[brand]
        else:
            parts_data[brand] = [part.get() for part in parts[brand]]
    parts_data = {brand: {part: var.get() for part, var in tab_parts.items()} for brand, tab_parts in parts.items()}

    # Save the parts to JSON file
    with open('parts.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(parts_data, file)

def load_parts():
    json_file = "parts.json"

    if os.path.exists(json_file):
        with open(json_file, "r") as file:
            try:
                parts.update(json.load(file))
                print("Parts loaded:")
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                # Handle invalid JSON file format
                print("Invalid JSON file format. Creating a new file with default data.")
                create_default_parts(json_file)
    else:
        print("JSON file not found. Creating a new file with default data.")
        create_default_parts(json_file)

    # Extract the brands from the JSON keys
    global brands
    with open(json_file) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        brands = list(data.keys())

def create_default_parts(json_file):
    default_parts = {
        "Brand 1": ["Part 1", "Part 2", "Part 3"],
        "Brand 2": ["Part 4", "Part 5", "Part 6"],
        "Brand 3": ["Part 7", "Part 8", "Part 9"]
    }

    parts_data = {brand: {part: var.get() for part, var in tab_parts.items()} for brand, tab_parts in parts.items()}

    # Save the parts to JSON file
    with open('parts.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(parts_data, file)

# Call the load_parts() function to load the parts data
load_parts()

def browse_master_folder_path(entry_widget):
    folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if folder_path:
        settings['master_folder_path'] = folder_path
        entry_widget.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry_widget.insert(tk.END, folder_path)

def browse_template_folder_path():
    folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if folder_path:
        settings['template_folder_path'] = folder_path
        destination_folder_entry.delete(0, tk.END)  # Update variable name here
        destination_folder_entry.insert(tk.END, folder_path)
        save_settings()

def create_documents():
    destination_folder = destination_folder_entry.get()
    if not os.path.exists(destination_folder):
        os.makedirs(destination_folder)

    for brand, tab_parts in parts.items():
        selected_parts = [part for part, var in tab_parts.items() if var.get()]

        for part in selected_parts:
            source_file = os.path.join(settings['master_folder_path'], brand, f'{part}.pdf')
            destination_file = os.path.join(destination_folder, f'{brand}_{part}.pdf')

            if os.path.exists(source_file):
                shutil.copy(source_file, destination_file)

    # Show a success message or perform any other necessary actions

selected_parts = []  # Declare the list before the ABB_ordersheet function

def ABB_ordersheet(excel_file):
    global selected_parts  # Add this line to access the global selected_parts list

    # Read the Excel file into a pandas DataFrame
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

    # Find the column index of the "Catalog No." column
    catalog_no_col = None
    start_row = 15  # Adjust this value based on the actual row index where the label "Catalog No." is present

    for col in df.columns:
        if "Catalog No." in df[col].tolist():
            catalog_no_col = col
            break


    # If "Catalog No." column is found, process the checkboxes
    # Get the part names from the checkboxes dictionary
    part_names = []
    for brand, tab_parts in parts.items():
        part_names += list(tab_parts.keys())

    # Iterate through the values beneath the "Catalog No." cell
    for row in range(start_row, len(df)):
        cell_value = df.loc[row, catalog_no_col]
        if cell_value in part_names:
            selected_parts.append(cell_value)

def upload_excel():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Excel Files', '*.xlsx;*.xls')])
    if file_path:
        ABB_ordersheet(file_path)
        check_checkboxes()

def check_checkboxes():
    global selected_parts  # Add this line to access the global selected_parts list

    # Iterate through the checkboxes and update their states
    for brand, tab_parts in parts.items():
        for part, var in tab_parts.items():
            if part in selected_parts:
                var.set(1)
            else:
                var.set(0)

# Initialize settings
load_settings()
load_parts()

# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("PDF Document Compiler")
window.geometry("550x450")

def open_settings():
    settings_window = tk.Toplevel(window)

    def save_settings_and_close():
        save_settings()
        settings_window.destroy()

    # Create and pack the necessary widgets

    master_folder_label = tk.Label(settings_window, text="Master Folder Path:")
    master_folder_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

    master_folder_entry = tk.Entry(settings_window)
    master_folder_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")
    master_folder_entry.insert(0, settings.get('master_folder_path', ''))  # Set default folder path
    master_folder_entry.configure(width=75)

    master_folder_button = tk.Button(settings_window, text="Browse",
                                     command=lambda: browse_master_folder_path(master_folder_entry))
    master_folder_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    save_button = tk.Button(settings_window, text="Save", command=save_settings_and_close)
    save_button.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    # Configure column 1 to expand horizontally when the window is resized wider
    settings_window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

checkboxes_frame = None  # Declare checkboxes_frame as a global variable
canvas = None
parts = {}
checkboxes_frames = {}
checkboxes = {}  # Define the checkboxes dictionary

def update_checkboxes(notebook, parts):
    global checkboxes_frames, checkboxes

    for brand, brand_parts in parts.items():
        # Check if the brand already has a tab
        brand_tab = None
        for tab in notebook.tabs():
            if notebook.tab(tab, option="text") == brand:
                brand_tab = tab
                break

        if brand_tab is None:
            # Create a new tab for the brand if it doesn't exist
            brand_tab = ttk.Frame(notebook)
            notebook.add(brand_tab, text=brand)
            checkboxes_frames[brand_tab] = ttk.Frame(brand_tab)
            checkboxes[brand] = []

        checkboxes_frame = checkboxes_frames[brand_tab]

        for part, var in brand_parts.items():
            if part not in checkboxes[brand]:
                checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(checkboxes_frame, text=part, variable=var)
                checkbox.pack(pady=5)
                checkboxes[brand].append(part)

    # Update the scroll region whenever the checkboxes frame changes size
    def update_scroll_region(event):
        canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

    checkboxes_frame.bind('<Configure>', update_scroll_region)

    # Create a window inside the canvas and place the checkboxes frame
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=checkboxes_frame, anchor="nw")
def create_main_window():
    global checkboxes_frame, canvas
    global menu_bar
    menu_bar = tk.Menu(window)
    window.config(menu=menu_bar)

    settings_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=False)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=settings_menu)

    settings_menu.add_command(label="Open Settings", command=open_settings)

    # Create a notebook with tabs
    notebook = ttk.Notebook(window)
    notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")  # Set columnspan to 5

    load_settings()


    global parts
    # Dictionary to store the parts checkboxes for each brand

    load_parts()
    brands = list(parts.keys())

    def create_default_brands():
        # Brands
        brands = ['ABB', 'Alps', 'Other']

    if not brands:
        create_default_brands()

    for brand in brands:
        # Create a frame for each tab
        tab = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        notebook.add(tab, text=brand)

        # Create a scrollable frame
        scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(tab)
        scrollable_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        # Create a canvas
        canvas = tk.Canvas(scrollable_frame)
        canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Add a scroll bar
        scroll_bar = ttk.Scrollbar(scrollable_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
        scroll_bar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        # Configure the canvas and scroll bar
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)
        canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e, c=canvas: c.configure(scrollregion=c.bbox("all")))

        # Create a frame inside the canvas to hold the checkboxes
        global checkboxes_frame
        checkboxes_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

        # Add additional parts for ABB TESTING FUNCTION ########################################
        if brand == "ABB":
            additional_parts = ["FA-TH", "CBX-8R8-H", "FLX-4R4-H", "FLX-8R8-H"]
            for part in additional_parts:
                var = tk.IntVar()
                checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(checkboxes_frame, text=part, variable=var)
                checkbox.pack(pady=5)
                parts[brand][part] = var

    update_checkboxes(notebook, parts)
create_main_window()

def add_part():
    # Create a new window for adding a part
    add_part_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
    add_part_window.title("Add Part")

    # Part Name Label and Entry
    part_name_label = ttk.Label(add_part_window, text="Part Name:")
    part_name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    part_name_entry = ttk.Entry(add_part_window)
    part_name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

    # PDF Location Label and Entry
    pdf_location_label = ttk.Label(add_part_window, text="PDF Location:")
    pdf_location_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    pdf_location_entry = ttk.Entry(add_part_window)
    pdf_location_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

    def browse_pdf_location():
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select PDF File", filetypes=(("PDF Files", "*.pdf"),))
        pdf_location_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        pdf_location_entry.insert(tk.END, filename)

    # Browse button for PDF Location
    browse_pdf_button = ttk.Button(add_part_window, text="Browse", command=browse_pdf_location)
    browse_pdf_button.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

    # Tab Selection Label and Combobox
    tab_selection_label = ttk.Label(add_part_window, text="Tab Selection:")
    tab_selection_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    tab_selection_combobox = Combobox(add_part_window, values=list(parts.keys()))
    tab_selection_combobox.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")



    def update_parts_list(brand):
        # Clear existing checkboxes for the brand
        #for child in parts[brand].keys():
         #   parts[brand][child].grid_forget()

        # Update parts and checkboxes
        for part, var in parts[brand].items():
            checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(checkboxes_frame, text=part, variable=var)
            checkbox.pack(pady=5)

    def add_part_to_tab():
        part_name = part_name_entry.get()
        pdf_location = pdf_location_entry.get()
        selected_tab = tab_selection_combobox.get()

        if selected_tab not in parts:
            parts[selected_tab] = {}

        parts[selected_tab][part_name] = tk.IntVar()

        # Save parts to JSON file
        with open('parts.json', 'r') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            if selected_tab not in data:
                data[selected_tab] = {}
            data[selected_tab][part_name] = pdf_location

        with open('parts.json', 'w') as file:
            json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

        part_name_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        pdf_location_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

        # Call update_parts_list with the selected_tab after adding the new part
        update_parts_list(selected_tab)

        add_part_window.destroy()



    # Add Part button
    add_part_button = ttk.Button(add_part_window, text="Add Part", command=add_part_to_tab)
    add_part_button.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

def save_part_data():
    part_data = {}
    for brand, part_dict in parts.items():
        part_data[brand] = {}
        for part, var in part_dict.items():
            part_data[brand][part] = var.get()

    parts_data = {brand: {part: var.get() for part, var in tab_parts.items()} for brand, tab_parts in parts.items()}

    # Save the parts to JSON file
    with open('parts.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(parts_data, file)

def remove_part():
    remove_part_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
    remove_part_window.title("Remove Part")

    # Tab Selection Label and Combobox
    tab_selection_label = ttk.Label(remove_part_window, text="Tab Selection:")
    tab_selection_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

    tab_selection_combobox = Combobox(remove_part_window, values=list(parts.keys()))
    tab_selection_combobox.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

    parts_listbox_remove = tk.Listbox(remove_part_window, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
    parts_listbox_remove.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

    def populate_parts_list():
        selected_tab = tab_selection_combobox.get()
        parts_listbox_remove.delete(0, tk.END)
        if selected_tab:
            if selected_tab in parts:
                parts_for_tab = parts[selected_tab]
                parts_listbox_remove.insert(tk.END, *parts_for_tab)
        else:
            first_tab = list(parts.keys())[0]  # Get the first tab
            if first_tab in parts:
                parts_for_tab = parts[first_tab]
                parts_listbox_remove.insert(tk.END, *parts_for_tab)

    tab_selection_combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda e: populate_parts_list())

    def remove_selected_parts():
        selected_tab = tab_selection_combobox.get()
        selected_indices = parts_listbox_remove.curselection()

        if messagebox.askyesno("Remove Parts", "Are you sure you want to remove the selected parts?"):
            selected_parts = [parts_listbox_remove.get(index) for index in selected_indices]
            if selected_tab in parts:
                parts[selected_tab] = [part for part in parts[selected_tab] if part not in selected_parts]

                # Update the JSON file
                parts_data = {brand: {part: var.get() for part, var in tab_parts.items()} for brand, tab_parts in
                              parts.items()}

                # Save the parts to JSON file
                with open('parts.json', 'w') as file:
                    json.dump(parts_data, file)

            # Remove parts from the main window listbox
            parts_listbox_remove.delete(0, tk.END)
            populate_parts_list()

            remove_part_window.destroy()  # Close the window after removal

    remove_button = ttk.Button(remove_part_window, text="Remove", command=remove_selected_parts)
    remove_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    populate_parts_list()

    remove_part_window.mainloop()

def save_and_exit():
    # Convert IntVar objects to integers
    parts_data = {brand: {part: var.get() for part, var in tab_parts.items()} for brand, tab_parts in parts.items()}

    # Save the parts to JSON file with original formatting
    with open('parts.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(parts_data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

    # Close the window
    window.destroy()

# Add Part button
add_part_button = tk.Button(window, text="Add Part", command=add_part)
add_part_button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

# Remove Part button
remove_part_button = tk.Button(window, text="Remove Part", command=remove_part)
remove_part_button.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

# Create the "Save and Exit" button
save_exit_button = tk.Button(window, text="Save and Exit", command=save_and_exit)
save_exit_button.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")


# Destination folder label and entry
destination_folder_label = tk.Label(window, text="Destination Folder:")
destination_folder_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

destination_folder_entry = tk.Entry(window)
destination_folder_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(10, 0), pady=10, sticky="ew")

# Browse button for destination folder
destination_folder_button = tk.Button(window, text="Browse", command=lambda: browse_template_folder_path())
destination_folder_button.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(0, 10), pady=10, sticky="ew")

# Compile button
compile_button = tk.Button(window, text="Compile", command=create_documents)
compile_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

# Open Settings button
open_settings_button = tk.Button(window, text="Open Settings", command=open_settings)
open_settings_button.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

# Upload Excel button
upload_excel_button = tk.Button(window, text="Upload Excel", command=upload_excel)
upload_excel_button.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=(0, 10), pady=10, sticky="ne")

# Configure the first row to expand vertically when the window is resized taller
window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Configure columns 0, 1, and 2 to expand horizontally when the window is resized wider
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

# Run the main event loop
window.mainloop()
```

Ive tried to look up other ways to go about this and even resorted to using ChatGPT to try and help as I don't have a super strong background in coding or in python, so any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is better to provide a simple JSON file example content for reference.

Comment: Thanks I forgot to add that, an example JSON file is included now

Comment: Inside `update_checkboxes()`, I think `checkboxes_frames[brand_tab] = ttk.Frame(brand_tab)` should be `checkboxes_frames[brand_tab] = brand_tab` instead.  Also you use `var` (which is an integer) for the `textvariable`, I think you need to use a dictionary to store the instances of `StringVar()` with `(brand, part)` as the key instead and pass instance of `StringVar()` to `textvariable` option instead.